# How to setup drop down list to update and save?

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I want to create a drop down list that allows the user to choose a Start and End "Year, Month, Day" as follows. When the page is updated, the choices are reverted to the "original" choices. How can I allow those selected values to save and remain when the page is updated?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['action']))
{
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    $startyear = $_POST['startyear'];
    $startmonth = $_POST['startmonth'];
    $startday = $_POST['startday'];
    $endyear = $_POST['endyear'];
    $endmonth = $_POST['endmonth'];
    $endday = $_POST['endday'];
}
else
{
    $action = "";
    if (!isset($_POST['startyear']) || !isset($_POST['startmonth']) || !isset($_POST['startday']) 
        || !isset($_POST['endyear']) || !isset($_POST['startmonth']) || !isset($_POST['startday']))
    {
        $startyear = "";
        $startmonth = "";
        $startday = "";
        $endyear = "";
        $endmonth = "";
        $endday = "";
    }
    else
    {
        $startyear = $_POST['startyear'];
        $startmonth = $_POST['startmonth'];
        $startday = $_POST['startday'];
        $endyear = $_POST['endyear'];
        $endmonth = $_POST['endmonth'];
        $endday = $_POST['endday'];
    }

}

if ($action == "update")
{
    echo "<h3>Start: $startyear-$startmonth-$startday | End: $endyear-$endmonth-$endday</h3>";
}

else
{
    if ($startyear == "" || $endyear == "")
    {
    // something belongs here...not sure
    }
    echo "<h3>Start: $startyear-$startmonth-$startday | End: $endyear-$endmonth-$endday</h3>";
?>
```

Selections for start/end year,month,day are here:

```
<form name='update' action='testing.php' method='POST'>
Start: <select name='startyear'>
    <option value="1">2012</option>
    <option value="2">2011</option>
    <option value="3">2010</option>
    <option value="4">2009</option>
    <option value="5">2008</option>
    <option value="6">2007</option>
    <option value="7">2006</option>
    <option value="8">2005</option>
    <option value="9">2004</option>
    <option value="10">2003</option>
    <option value="11'>2002</option>
    <option value="12">2001</option>
    <option value="13">2000</option>
    <option value="14">1999</option>
    <option value="15">1998</option>
</select>
<select name='startmonth'>
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="2">02</option>
    <option value="3">03</option>
    <option value="4">04</option>
    <option value="5">05</option>
    <option value="6">06</option>
    <option value="7">07</option>
    <option value="8">08</option>
    <option value="9">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
    <select name='startday'>
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="2">02</option>
    <option value="3">03</option>
    <option value="4">04</option>
    <option value="5">05</option>
    <option value="6">06</option>
    <option value="7">07</option>
    <option value="8">08</option>
    <option value="9">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<br>
End:<select name ='endyear'>
    <option value="1">2012</option>
    <option value="2">2011</option>
    <option value="3">2010</option>
    <option value="4">2009</option>
    <option value="5">2008</option>
    <option value="6">2007</option>
    <option value="7">2006</option>
    <option value="8">2005</option>
    <option value="9">2004</option>
    <option value="10">2003</option>
    <option value="11'>2002</option>
    <option value="12">2001</option>
    <option value="13">2000</option>
    <option value="14">1999</option>
    <option value="15">1998</option>
</select>
<select name='endmonth'>
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="2">02</option>
    <option value="3">03</option>
    <option value="4">04</option>
    <option value="5">05</option>
    <option value="6">06</option>
    <option value="7">07</option>
    <option value="8">08</option>
    <option value="9">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
    <select name='endday'>
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="2">02</option>
    <option value="3">03</option>
    <option value="4">04</option>
    <option value="5">05</option>
    <option value="6">06</option>
    <option value="7">07</option>
    <option value="8">08</option>
    <option value="9">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<input type='submit' value='Compare'/>
</form>
 <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: Actually, the saving to variables is working. But when the page is updated, the choices are brought back to the "original" choices, which are "2012" "01" "01". I don't want them to be reverted to the "original" choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having such large HTML let php render it for you, this also allows you to determine if the **selected** attribute is rendered in the option.

To keep the values selected in the form the form needs tobe posted back to the same php script its being rendered from `action=''`, and a little logic is required on the posted values to check if the value equals itself, check the form below.

```
<?php 
//Build an array of values for your forms
$year  = range(1998,2012);
$month = range(01,12);
$day   = range(01,31);

//Handle POST, just an example
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
        if(is_numeric($value)){
            $$key = $value;
        }
    }
    /**
     * All POST keys like: startmonth ect will now be php variables like
     * $startmonth
     */

    //Do somthing with $startmonth ect
}

//A more tidy form
?>
<form name='update' action='' method='POST'>
Start: <select name='startyear'>
    <?php foreach(array_reverse($year) as $y):?>
    <option value="<?=$y?>"<?=((isset($startyear) && $startyear == $y)?' selected':null)?>><?=$y?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
<select name='startmonth'>
    <?php foreach($month as $m): $m = str_pad($m, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);?>
    <option value="<?=$m;?>"<?=((isset($startmonth) && $startmonth == $m)?' selected':null)?>><?=$m;?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
    <select name='startday'>
    <?php foreach($day as $d): $d = str_pad($d, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);?>
    <option value="<?=$d;?>"<?=((isset($startday) && $startday == $d)?' selected':null)?>><?=$d;?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
<br>
End: <select name='endyear'>
    <?php foreach(array_reverse($year) as $y):?>
    <option value="<?=$y?>"<?=((isset($endyear) && $endyear == $y)?' selected':null)?>><?=$y?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
<select name='endmonth'>
    <?php foreach($month as $m): $m = str_pad($m, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);?>
    <option value="<?=$m;?>"<?=((isset($endmonth) && $endmonth == $m)?' selected':null)?>><?=$m;?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
    <select name='endday'>
    <?php foreach($day as $d): $d = str_pad($d, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);?>
    <option value="<?=$d;?>"<?=((isset($endday) && $endday == $d)?' selected':null)?>><?=$d;?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
<input type='submit' value='Compare'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a little more to the HTML that's generating your page, to set up a default selected value for your dropdowns.

You'll need something like this:

```
<option value="1" <?php if ($_POST["startyear"] = "1") echo "selected"; ?>>2012</option>
```

You'll need to do that for each option, to see if this option's value is the same as the one from `$_POST`; you might want to look into using a `for` loop to create the HTML, in that case.